# What does "if they're a pound" mean?

Tags: dialogue, sherlock-holmes-2009

In the movie *Sherlock Holmes* (2009) I came across the following sentence:

> These slabs of sandstone are half a ton each, **if they’re a pound**, and
> they’re smashed open from the inside.

I don't understand what this **"if they're a pound"** part means here. Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256960/origin-of-the-phrase-it-s-been-years-if-it-s-been-a-day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an idiom. The “if they’re a pound” phrase is an ironic way of stating “if they weigh anything at all (and I know they do).” The meaning of the entire sentence is thus “if these slabs of sandstone weigh something, (and they do), they weigh at least half a ton each” or, more directly, “these slabs weigh at least half a ton each”

Comment: I wonder why I couldn't find this idiom in any dictionary...

Comment: @JConstantine - It works with lots of different units. [Here's](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Australian_Journal/a4pGAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22if+they%E2%80%99re+an+inch%22&pg=PA418&printsec=frontcover) an example from the 1800s where it's *"...if they're an inch"*

Comment: Is this more like an old-fashioned idiomatic expression, or it perfectly works these days too and doesn't sound like something from the past?

Comment: I would say this is a bit abstract but definitely not old-fashioned.

Comment: I’ve heard it with age. “It’s 100 years old if it’s a day”, etc.

Comment: May be worth adding that ‘pound’ here is the [unit of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(mass)) (and not the [UK currency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sterling)).  These days people are increasingly likely to think of mass in terms of grams and kilograms, but many old references persist — and of course, this movie was set long before metrication.